# Sorting list by value of division

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda, key

I'm trying to learn Python and I faced such problem.

I have a list:

```
a = [[10,5],[9,3],[16,2],[8,8]]
```

I want to get a list that will be sorted desc by value of divion arr[i][0]/arr[i][1]. For example for list a (after sorting) I want to have:

```
a =[[8,8],[10,5],[9,3],[16,2]]
```

I tried to use lambda in a.sort(key = lambda .....) but I failed.

Could you please help me to understand how it must be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with a `key`, like, so:

```
>>> a = [[10,5],[9,3],[16,2],[8,8]]
>>> sorted(a, key= lambda x: x[0]/x[1])
[[8, 8], [10, 5], [9, 3], [16, 2]]
```

From the Docs,

```
key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element
```

Here, the `lambda` function returns the answer of dividing the first element by the second using

```
lambda x: x[0]/x[1]
```

Comment: I was reading this: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/ but maybe missed smth. Thank you!

Comment: It talks about the Key functions, that's what we used here, the lambda gets each element of the list like `[10, 5]`, `[9, 3]` and so on, and returns the division which is used to sort the list.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say whether you're using Python2 or Python3. In Python2 you need to make sure it's a floating point divison

```
>>> a = [[10,5],[9,3],[16,2],[8,8]]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: float(x[0]) / x[1])
[[8, 8], [10, 5], [9, 3], [16, 2]]
```

If there's a chance of division by 0, you'll need something like this

```
>>> sorted(a, key= lambda x: float(x[0])/x[1] if x[1] else float('inf'))>>> from
```

Another way is to use `Fraction` which avoids the precision problems of `float`. Unfortunately `Fraction` is not available for 2.4

```
fractions import Fraction
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x:Fraction(*x))
[[8, 8], [10, 5], [9, 3], [16, 2]]
```

Comment: Python 2.4. There is no chance for division by 0, but I totally forgot about float(). Does from __future__ import division will also help for correct division at lambda functions?

Comment: @geluinie, yes of course `from __future__ import division` also works